# Argument error in Angular10 + Firebase project

Tags: angular, firebase

Here is the error I am getting:

[image]

Comment: You should give some more detail, what are you trying to achieve etc.

Comment: Please don't post images of code/error messages. Copy them into your post and format them appropriately.